# C fgets - simple way to catch overflow?

Tags: c, overflow, fgets

Very simple example - hoping for a simple solution:

```
char x[7];
if(fgets(x,5,stdin))
    printf("y");
else
    printf("n");
```

I can't seem to get it to print "n" when I input more than the byte limit - is there any simple way I could enforce it or catch when it's surpassed?

As a side question, what example inputs would actually cause an "n" in the above snippet? I'm not really seeing the point right now..

Cheers,
B

Comment: Note that fgets needs the buffer size (7) as argument, not the size with space for newline and nul characters subtracted (5).

Comment: Yeah I done that on purpose to emphasise the fact that it couldn't fit

Comment: This question in various forms has been asked here zillion times and answer is in man page ;/

Comment: I don't suppose you can point out were on the man page it shows how to catch when input has overflowed? Pretty sure it says it stops reading in once size-1 has been reached, which is definitely not what I'm asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgets returns NULL only if it failed to read anything, which usually means end of file.

Since fgets reads a line, or as many characters of that line that fit in the buffer, you need to check if your variable x contains a newline character.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` will return 0 when it fails, so to get 'n' as an output, you'd use control-D or control-Z (or whatever your OS uses to indicate end of input) without entering anything else first.

To detect when more has been entered than you've left room to read, check whether the last character you read was a new-line. If it is, you read a whole line. If it's not, there's more waiting.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'd need to check if there's still data waiting in stdin via `select()` or the like.
2. Redirecting `/dev/null` or a 0-byte file into stdin could to it.

Comment: Bah I can't figure out how to use select... It seems like it monitors some sort of FD..? But it also seems like the right answer.. Is while looping through the whole input and checking for '\0' the easiest way like these other gentle(wo)men recommend, or is there something amazing like stdin.length?